# Mutual fund theorem

Tags: finance-mathematics

Theorem (Mutual fund theorem in the case that there is one risk-less asset and at least one risky asset). Suppose that all preced- ing assumptions in this subsection are valid. Consider the constant portfolios $w^r$ and $w^{\mu}$ defined by $\sum_{I=1}^{N} w^{\mu ,I}(0,w^{\mu ,1}, \dots, w^{\mu ,N})^T$ is the relative portfolio that corresponds to $w^{\mu}$
. what is the nature of the constant portfolios $w^r$ and $w^{\mu}$? Are they relative portfolios? \

I start with is problem by thing of the remark: 
The theorem means that an economic agent in our setting is indifferent between investing in an optimal portfolio con- sisting of the assets in our market model and investing in a portfolio consisting of just two mutual funds, where one of them is the risk-less asset and the other one consists of only risky assets. Also, we have that
$$w^r:=(1,0,\dots , 0),$$
$$[0,T]\times \Omega \to R^{1+N}$$
$$w^{\mu}:= \begin{bmatrix}1&0\\
0 & (\sigma \sigma ^T)^{-1} \end{bmatrix}
(0,\mu ^1 -r, \dots, \mu ^N -r),$$
$$[0,T]\times \Omega \to R^{1+N}$$

I know there is problem with the vector $w^{\mu}$.

Comment: what do you mean by "subsubsection"? what does $r$ and $\mu$ represent? why is there a blank cell in $w^{\mu}$, and is the matrix in square brackets supposed to be multiplied against the second vector in soft brackets? if so, what are their shapes in real number space and what is $\sigma$ and its shape?

Comment: Sorry is mistake in typing.

Comment: It is [0,T]\times \omega which is go to R^{N+1}

Comment: sigma is a real N times d matrix (volatility matrix)

Comment: what is \omega, $d$, $N$, $r$, and $\mu$

Comment: I add some more details

Comment: d is just diagonal matrix